# Array.sort() not working for date objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why `Array.prototype.sort()` doesn't work for date objects:

```
var x = [new Date("2015-03-16"), new Date("2015-02-24"), new Date("2015-03-13")];
x.sort(); // [Fri Mar 13 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Mon Mar 16 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Feb 24 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)]
x[0] <= x[1]; // true
x[1] <= x[2]; // false !!!!!!
```

I know how I can get them to sort nicely (by using `x.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b; });`, however I'd like to understand why {both Chrome and Safari} don't sort elements in an array in the order it knows about (when using `<`)

Comment: Dates are really numbers, so sorting by valueOf is simple. if you compare as strings, then results are not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It actually seems that the spec (or at least, [what mozilla wites about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) is to blame (my emphasis):

> Parameters - compareFunction
>
> Optional. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, **according to the string conversion of each element**.

Since the string conversion starts with the day of the week, dates will always be sorted alphabetically: Fri, Mon, Sat, Sun, Thu, Tue, Wed....

Comment: Yes, it's the spec who defines this behavior. See steps 13-18 of the SortCompare abstract operation, in [section 15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems a bit convoluted but if you want to evade passing arguments to the `sort` method altogether, this should work:

`x.map(function (ele) {
    return ele.valueOf();
  }).sort().map(function (ele) {
    return new Date(ele);
  });`

Comment: OP knows how to sort (as numbers), but that doesn't explain the behavior he asked about.